# Implication of ending Unity

Tags: unity, gnome, application-development, window-manager

Ubuntu 18.x will carry Gnome Window mgr instead of Unity window mgr.

What is the implication in application development?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Not all that much.

Essentially as long as you have the appropriate frameworks (Both Gnome and Unity are based off GTK), applications will keep running exactly as designed. I suppose unity lenses and [a few other things](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65321/characteristics-of-unity-and-gnome3-for-the-end-user?rq=1) may no longer work until the bits of dash that make it work are ported.

People have been officially *not* running unity as a desktop longer than there's been Ubuntu (which started off as a gnome based distribution). It simply means Ubuntu will be more closely aligned on the desktop with debian, which is a positive thing in most cases.

*Unless* you're programming specifically for Unity, it means absolutely nothing at all. Server side or non graphical applications will remain entirely the same for example.

Linux has dozens and dozens of desktop environments, and switching between them has typically been mostly painless. Properly skinned (and Ubuntu is good at this) and presumably with a few small bits of software to act as glue for features Gnome Shell does not have, you probably will not notice the difference.